# How can I put a Kubernetes Secret in a Cronjob curl command?

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, yaml, el

In kubernetes I have a secret defined, and in my deploy-templates YAML files, I have that secret set as ${mySecret}.

I am trying to create a CronJob that uses the following CURL to run the Job with the header info defined in the secret. No matter what I do, the ${mySecret} doesn't seem to get turned into the correct information.

Do I have to define it some other way in the YAML?

```
apiVersion: myjob/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-cronjobs
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          initContainers:
          - name: my-job
            image: curlimages/curl
            command: ["sh", "-c", "curl --location --request POST \"http://myservice:8080/api/endpoint\" --header \"my-secret: ${mySecret}\""]
```

Tried to use ${} in a yaml-based curl command. I expected the value to be parsed and run the job correctly. In reality, I get a BAD REQUEST error from the job every hour.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the secret to the env-vars of your container.
Suppose you have a `my-secret` secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  THE_SECRET: dG9wU2VjcmV0MTIz
```

Then you can reference the value in `THE_SECRET` in your cron-job like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-cronjobs
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-job
            image: curlimages/curl
            command: ["sh", "-c", "curl --location --request POST \"http://myservice:8080/api/endpoint\" --header \"my-secret: ${THE_SECRET}\""]
            envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: my-secret
            - secretRef:
                name: other-secret
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I already had it defined in my deployment yaml but I guess it wasn't picking up. Is it possible to have more than one?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple. The `-` before `secretRef` indicates that this is an array.
So you could just add another `secretRef` (I've added an example in the answer)

Comment: Thank you, but I've been struggling for a few hours and the keys I have saved aren't being loaded

`initContainers:
      - name: my-job
        image: curlimages/curl
        command: ["sh", "-c", "curl --location --request POST \"http://myservice:8080/api/endpoint\" --header \"my-secret: ${mySecret}\""]
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
               name: my-secret
      - name: my-job2
        image: curlimages/curl
        command: ["sh", "-c", "curl --location --request POST \"http://myservice:8080/api/endpoint2\" --header \"my-secret: ${mySecret}\""]
etc.`

Comment: This is really hard to read. Maybe you can add this to your question?
It would be helpful, if you could provide both resources, the cron-job and the secret (of course, replace the secret-values with some dummy-data).
Also, you might add an `env` to your command to see what's your actual environment.
And BTW - not sure, but I think you can't have only init-containers - you do need at least one container.